# No Tablespace found during dump import

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, partitioning, tablespaces

**Original Question:**

**Oracle dump imported with zero rows**

I have exported the oracle dump from source by using

```
exp username/password file=filepath/filname.dump
```

I tried to import the exported dump into another system/oracle DB by using the following command

created a new user in dest system

```
imp file=filepath/filname.dump fromuser=sourceuser touser=createddestuser

username:sys as sysdba

password:******
```

All tables imported successfully

But zero records in all imported tables.

This is the first time i have facing the problem.Please help me soon.Thanks in advance.

***In Source DB there are two tablespace called tablespace 1 and tablespace 2,but in destination DB there is no such tablespace.So I created manually in dest system and Dump imported successfully with all rows.***

**Updated Question:**

Should i need the same tablespace in destination system as same as source system for DUMP import??

Comment: What was in the respective log files?  Were there errors (perhaps quota related)?  Does the export log show that there was data in the export file?

Comment: connecting as sysdba?  Let's see what the Utilities Manual has to say about that: "SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for generalized users. Therefore, you should not typically need to invoke Import as SYSDBA, except in the following situations:   At the request of Oracle technical support     When importing a transportable tablespace set"  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#SUTIL1643

Comment: In source DB there is tablespace called tablespace1 and tablespace2.But in Destination there is no such Tablespace.So some of the tables as well as rows for all tables are not imported.I created the two tablspace and imported successfully.Should i need to keep the same tablespace in destination system as same as source destination??Is any solution to avoid this problem??Thx @justin and Edstevens.

Comment: If you were using the modern DataPump versions of export and import, there would be a remap_tablespace option.  Using the old school, you can create the tables in a different tablespace before importing.  That's generally the easiest option.  If you have access to the source, you can use `dbms_metadata` to generate the DDL and modify that.  Otherwise, you can use the `indexfile` option of `imp` to generate a file with the DDL from the dump file.